# how to set style to the button from code behind through observable collection in windows phone 8

Tags: windows-phone-8, styles, observablecollection, background-color, code-behind

I am facing a problem, I have an observable collection which is hiding/showing the button and changing the text as well according to situation. Everything is working fine.

But now I want to change the background color and foreground color of the button from the code behind at runtime OR I want to set the Style from the code behind. Is it possible or if possible then how?

I tried to create a Style Property in my observable collection and tried to set, but it didn't work, please help me what and where I am going wrong ?

Answer (score 1):

style from code behind can be set easily like this

Note: I am supposing that the style is being created in page resources.

```
 btn.Style = (Style)this.Resources["Style Name"];
```

Comment: You are supposing that it is created in the App.xaml file (app resources). To access Page resources in code behind you can access them with this.Resources["myResourceName"].

Comment: @eX0du5 aahh my bad!!.. I was committing a very silly mistake. Thanks anways

Comment: i tried following way also.

btns.Style = (Style)Application.Current.Resources["CustomReadButton"];

but it didn't work for me.

Comment: where is your style declared? is it in the same page or it is declared in a global file?

Comment: It is declared in the App.xaml

Comment: Why do you use an ObservableCollection with 1 button?